# Bundle.get() deprecated. How to fix this when converting to map with Any type?

Tags: android, kotlin, bundle

`Bundle.get(key: String)` is deprecated:

> Use the type-safe specific APIs depending on the type of the item to be retrieved, eg. getString(String).

So how to solve this in this method? Don't think I can use generic T here because the Bundle can contain multiple different types. I feel like I have to know the type of the key I'm trying to retrieve before retrieving it, is that even possible?

```
private fun Bundle.toMap(): Map<String?, *> {
    val map = mutableMapOf<String?, Any?>()
    for (key in keySet()) {
        map[key] = get(key)
    }
    return map
}
```

Comment: How much of data are you trying to send via `Bundle`?

Comment: It's used for analytics events. It's just a few values max per method call, let's say on average just 2, max 10. The method can be called several times a second.